# HTML, disable highlighting/copying prompts in code listings

Tags: css

I'd like to put some code listings on a web page. Sometimes they're lists of commands to be copied. I'd like to show prompts in those code listings, yet make them somehow non-copyable, so that when user copies the text, he won't copy the prompts by mistake.

Note that I don't want to “protect” the content, I just want to help user not make mistake.

I tried to apply [CSS rules to disable text selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting), but it seems that even then if you highlight and copy multiple commands at once, prompts are copied together with the text—at least this is what I see in Google Chrome. [Try for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/4TXJs/3/), what gets into my clipboard is:

```
def hello(text):
   ....:     print "Hello {}!".format(text)
   ....:     print "Bye, cruel {}!".format(text)
   ....: 

In [24]: def foo(bar):
   ....:     print 'Another helper function.'
   ....:     bar.boom()
   ....:
```

So, how to do it right?